# Why does changing the HeaderStyle of a ListView hang the application?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listview

I've been trying to fix this issue and it seems to be a problem from the .Net framework. anyway, I have a listview which contains 5000+ items and a button used to do further processing to the selected items in the listview. now clicking this button should also set "listview.HeaderStyle" property of the listview to "ColumnHeaderStyle.Nonclickable".
now when I do that. the program hangs for like 10 seconds then continues its work. I have no idea what is causing and why this is happening. I hope you guys have a solution for this.
any ideas?

Comment: It doesn't particularly surprise me that this would create a few seconds delay. The framework probably re-creates the native ListView control whenever you set the property, which takes a while. It's worth noting that 5000+ items are a lot to have in a ListView...

Comment: is there any workaround solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a basic solution for now, all I need is to set

`myListview.ColumnClick += new ColumnClickEventHandler(delegate{});`

Now I don't need to change "listview.HeaderStyle" property anymore.
basically I was disabling the `ColumnClick` event from the `HeaderStyle` property and that's all. so instead of setting the HeaderStyle to nonClickable. I just remove/change the function inside event handler.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem using `BackgroundWorker` [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx).

**Note** : Even using this solution your form will hang for some time. Because you have 5000+ items to be bind to the list, which will **block your UI thread**, hence winform will hang. But your `listview.HeaderStyle` will get modified.

Try this

1. On button click, you directly change the propert of `listview.HeaderStyle` to `ColumnHeaderStyle.Nonclickable`. Then call `RunWorkerAsync` of `BackgroundWorker`.
2. On `DoWork` event handler you do the processing, and once done bind data to list view. To do this you will need to add following extension class to your project.

Extension Class

```
public static class ControlExtensions
{
    public static void Invoke(this Control control, Action action)
    {
        if (control.InvokeRequired) control.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(action), null);
        else action.Invoke();
    }
}
```

Using this you can bind data to listview

```
listview.Invoke(() => ( listview.DataSource = dataSource; });
```

Hope this works for you.

Comment: thanks for the idea.. but it really doesn't do much of a difference.. I just thought of another easier solution which will probably won't block anything... its changing the Columnclick event to empty function.

Comment: That's the idea, you do all your computation on a background thread, and keep your UI thread free from it. UI thread should only handle the rendering part and not the computation ideally.